# how to log errors in iis7.5 and MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7.5

I have written an application using MVC4.

After I depolyed it to production, I noticed I get the errors

```
server could not process you request
```

from time to time.  Its not function related as if I do the same action as before the system works no errors.  So I want to find more information about what is causing the issue

how do I log errors in iis 7.5? where should I be looking?

I looked at `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC2` which is where logging is occuring in my application through iis, but I went through the files and could not see anything that looked like an error..

is there something in particular I should be looking for?

Thanks

Comment: You may have a look at the system event log?

Comment: Why not try using [ELMAH](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/).

Comment: developer10214 - I did look at the event logs but could not find anything

Comment: CallMeKags - Might give ELMAH a try - thanks